# std::string::operator=(char): Which compiler is right? And how to test for this kind of bug?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, std

I tripped upon this strange bug in my code.  The bug itself is quite common... Since I had a test case open, I decided to test for it...  I found it was quite hard to test for this condition.

Here is an overview of the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// simulating what is the C driver FYI, it's the alsa sound driver, 
// but that's not much relevant

char* some_text = nullptr;

void init_text()
{
    some_text = strdup("some text");
}

int get_card_name(int, char** x)
{
    *x = some_text;
    return 0;
}

//  end 'driver' code  
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char* name;
    std::string s;

     // my original bug...  &"à! happens.
     s = get_card_name(i, &name);

     // Should have read:
     // if (!get_card_name(i, &name))
     //    s = name;

    // simulating EXPECT_FALSE(s.empty());
    std::cout << "s.empty()      : " << s.empty() << '\n';

    // simulating EXPECT_NE(s.length(), 0);
    std::cout << "s.length()     : " << s.length() << '\n';

    // simulating EXPECT_NE(s, "");
    std::cout << "(s == \"\")      : " << (s == "") << '\n';

    // a trace to check contents:
    std::cout << "s              : \"" << s << "\"\n";

    if (!s.empty())
        std::cout << "int(s.front()) : " << (int)s.front() << '\n';

    free(some_text);
    return s.length();
}
```

It looks straightforward, but here is the output with gcc 10.2 -Wall, but no warnings :( :

```
s.empty()      : 0
s.length()     : 1
(s == "")      : 0
s              : ""
int(s.front()) : 0
```

With clang 11.0.1 -Wall, but no warnings :( :

```
s.empty()      : 0
s.length()     : 1
(s == "")      : 0
s              : ""
int(s.front()) : 0
```

And with msvc 19.28 -Wall, and over 100 lines of warnings :( :

```
s.empty()      : 1
s.length()     : 0
(s == "")      : 1
s              : ""
```

This rather trivial, bug of mine turns out to be quite difficult to test for, at least for gcc and clang.  Three questions come to mind...

- which compiler is right?
- Detecton is not so obvious.  How can we protect against this kind of 'easy' bug?
- Are the gcc and clang stl implementations to blame? Should I report a bug?

You will find the code here as well: https://godbolt.org/z/9WhaGzTz8

[EDIT]  As food for thought...

Taking the string s from the code above... Since my main concern is corect unit testing for detecting bugs in production code.

gcc and clang report

```
 (s == s.c_str()) is false
```

This does catch the bug, but the inequality looks strange... Does this mean that something is broken with respect to the standard?

Comment: FWIW, if you had used `std::string s = get_card_name(i, &name);`, all compilers would have given you an error.

Comment: @NathanOliver As pointed out, gcc and clang give no warnings and no compilation errors with the -Wall flag set.

Comment: What is MSVC 19.28 ? With Visual Studio 2019, I get `0 1 0 " " 0`. Most warnings are unrelated to your code.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica   The basic_string<>::operator=(CharT) gets called.  I spent more time debugging the test than the original bug.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  That's the most recent release version of msvc on godbolt.  vs2019 16.9 -Wall, it behaves the best , even though the warnings are quite verbose.

Comment: The bug is that you can assign an `int` to a `std::string`? Why don't you mention that in your opening paragraph instead of making readers go through the trouble of reading over 50 lines of code to figure out what you are asking about?

Comment: gcc and clang create a special string almost like a NaN ("NaS"). It feels empty, smells empty, but has length 1. Could well be that the difference is in the implementation detail whether data is allocated for a default-constructed string so that there is a natural terminating 0 byte. If not, explicitly assigning one leads to an allocation and a length of one byte (the new 0); if data is already there though, effectively assigning 0 to s[0] does not change anything.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy They do?  It gives an error here: https://godbolt.org/z/cbr7fh1qP

Comment: Not germane to the question, but `some_text` is never initialized.

Comment: @JaMiT  It is OK to have a feature to assign a chat to a string, and make it a string of length 1, but if the char is null, it may bring trouble.  And it's very difficult to test for, that's where it gets very annoying.

Comment: @NathanOliver  It doesn't here: https://godbolt.org/z/ojbrbj4q6  which is odd, because supposedly using the same stl.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy You're using `s = get_card_name(i, &name);`.  In my example, I'm using `std::string s = get_card_name(i, &name);`.  There is a difference there.  The first one is assignment, while the second is initialization.  `std""string` doesn't have a constructor to be constructed by a single char, so it'll turn into an error.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy That  may be. I find it annoying to have to read code to understand what a question is asking. (Also, it goes against the advice in [ask] regarding the opening paragraph.) Guess we're both going to end up annoyed here.

Answer (score 2):

> which compiler is right?

The following output is correct:

> ```
> s.empty()      : 0
> s.length()     : 1
> (s == "")      : 0
> s              : ""
> int(s.front()) : 0
> ```

`s = get_card_name(i, &name);` should invoke `basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );` which should result in the the string containing a single character object. In this case, the value is 0 which means that the string would contain a single null terminator (in addition to the null terminator after the content of the string).

> How can we protect against this kind of 'easy' bug?

Initialise variables directly, instead of assigning later. It's usually the best practice and in this case would have protected you because string doesn't have a constructor accepting a single integer.

```
std::string s = get_card_name(); // ill-formed
```

There are also compiler options to warn about implicit conversions:

> ```
> warning: conversion from 'int' to 'char' may change value [-Wconversion]
> ```

Such option is usually too noisy to be enabled unconditionally, but it may be occasionally useful when you know there is a bug that you need to locate.

---

Also avoid "output" parameters when they are unnecessary. In this case:

```
char* get_card_name()
{
    return some_text;
}

std::string s = get_card_name(); // works as expected
```

Of course, this is more about how to write the API, not about how to deal with APIs that are difficult to use. With those, you need careful diligence.

It would be a good idea to implement an easier to use wrapper API so that the C-style API doesn't need to be used directly.

---

> Are the gcc and clang stl implementations to blame? Should I report a bug?

No. They work correctly.

Comment: Good thing C++ has a few of these APIs built-in (from the beginning!) to teach us all the need for careful diligence, always an important skill for a developer to have and improve!

Comment: I agree with the direvct assignment when possible...But it is never this easy, since as is often the case, my actual string lives inside a structure, and is not isolated as in the code posted.  Some compilers apparently do detect the null char and set the string length to 0.  Which is also probably correct. since `std::string x = bad_string.c_str()`  creates a string that has a different valuie than the 'bad' string.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy It's not correct behaviour according to the C++ standard, whether some compilers do that or not.

Comment: @eerorika  My thoughts exacly.  It only happens with zero, which is the most common value.  Adding `EXPECT_EQ(s, s.c_str());` to all unit testing doesn't seem like a bad idea now.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy If the string is supposed to not contain null terminators, then that would be a reasonable way to check that.